# Fetch ticker news from facebook

Tags: javascript, python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would fetch data from my facebook ticker sidebar 
(see the image below)
 [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGx81.jpg)

I would fetch this data to create a sort of analysis. I would use python, but I can also consider Javascript, and then I may pass these data (JSON format maybe) to my python code for the next analysis.
I really don't know how to fetch these Ticker data.
Here what I tried and searched on google:

1) I tried to fetch the data with `selenium` + `python` but I wasn't able to get the data througt its class div. Facebook generates dinamically its div class and I was a little confused in how to overpass this.

2) I serached `Facebook Graph API` and I read that (maybe) I might use `/{user-id}/feed` to fetch these data. I really don't understand if this function will returns only my data (my comments on others posts or the posts in which I was tagged) or all my Ticker sidebar news (friends activity). I want all my Ticker sidebar news, not only posts referred to me. Before to try this I would know if someone knows the answer.

3) I think that in Js I should try to create an Ajax request and fetch these data to pass in my python cliend to display them. But I don't know I should do this and If is it possibile.

Thank you.

Comment: Scraping is not allowed, and via API this kind of info is not available.

Comment: ok I find a solution. You can close. Thank you

Comment: @BossShell what's the solution you find ?

Comment: @BossShell can you provide the solution here?